# Iterate through complex json object C#

Tags: c#, json

I am receiving JSON in the below format. And I need to store the parent and child maintaining its relation to database.

```
{
  "hour": {
    "Hour Access": {
      "labels": "Hour Access",
      "DisplayId": 2,
      "InputCodeValue": 1
    },
    "Hour": {
      "labels": "Hour",
      "DisplayId": 3,
      "InputCodeValue": 2
    },
    "DisplayId": 1
  },
  "patient": {
    "Doctor Patient": {
      "labels": "Doctor Patient",
      "DisplayId": 5,
      "InputCodeValue": 3
    },
    "Patient Portal": {
      "labels": "Patient Portal",
      "DisplayId": 6,
      "InputCodeValue": 4
    },
    "Patient Transportation": {
      "labels": "Patient Transportation",
      "DisplayId": 7,
      "InputCodeValue": 5
    },
    "Patient": {
      "labels": "Patient",
      "DisplayId": 8,
      "InputCodeValue": 6
    },
    "DisplayId": 4
  }
}
```

For achieving the result I need to iterate through JSON. And so far I have tried this:

```
JObject jObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(prod.ToString());
            foreach (var level1 in jObj)
            {
                var jObjKey = level1.Key;
                foreach (var level2 in level1.Value)
                {
                    //JObject finalLoop = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(level2.ToString());//Error
                }
            }
```

In level2 I get the value to which I am unable to iterate to fetch the value.

level2:

```
{"Hour Access": {
  "labels": "Hour Access",
  "DisplayId": 2,
  "InputCodeValue": 1
}}
```

[image]

Comment: Why can't you deserialize to object model and then your itertion would become easy

Comment: My JSON is not constant. It can vary.

Comment: how are you expecting to do anything meaningful with a blob of data, if you don't know the model of your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your logic a bit to read the child object

```
JObject jObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString.ToString());
foreach (var level1 in jObj)
{
    var jObjKey = level1.Key;

    //get the final loop here before foreach
    JObject finalLoop = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(level1.Value.ToString());
    foreach (var level2 in finalLoop)
    {
        //check whether the level2 have keyvaluepair
        if (level2.Value.Count()>1)
        {
            //push the keyvaluepair to dictionary or dynamic object
            Dictionary<string, object> dictObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(level2.Value.ToString());
            if (dictObj.Keys.Contains("labels"))
            { 
                Console.WriteLine(dictObj["labels"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```